# Замена символа на другой

Tags: java, строки

Заменить все вхождения символа стоящего в позиции (3) на символ стоящий в позиции 0. Не подскажите как сделать? Именно с индекса 0 на индекс 3, я знаю только с помощью replace

Comment: 1) прочитать что там за символы 2) string.replace(…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для *замены* всех вхождений можно применить replaceAll, но здесь придется заэкранировать символы при помощи `Pattern.quote`:

```java
String str = "|$$$|+++|-$-|";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(str.substring(3, 4)), str.substring(0, 1)));
// -> |||||+++|-|-|
```

При использовании `replace` экранирование выполняется по умолчанию:

```
System.out.println(str.replace(str.substring(3, 4), str.substring(0, 1)));
```

---

Для *перестановки* двух символов можно применить `String.replaceFirst` с такой регуляркой: `"^(.)(..)(.)"`, просто переставив группы в обратной последовательности `"$3$2$1"`,

- группа 1 `^(.)` с якорем начала строки соответствует `charAt(0)`,
- группа 2 `(..)` - символы между 0-м и 3-м, может быть записана как `(.{2})`
- группа 3 -- `charAt(3)`

```java
String str = "Swap Letters";
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("^(.)(..)(.)", "$3$2$1"));
```

Результат:

```
pwaS Letters
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String exampleStr = "Hello, World!";
            // Замена всех символов с 0 позиции ('H') на символ с 3 позиции ('l')
            System.out.println(replaceAllByIndex(exampleStr, 0, 3));
            // Замена всех символов с 4 позиции ('o') на символ с 12 позиции ('!')
            System.out.println(replaceAllByIndex(exampleStr, 4, 12));
        }

        public static String replaceAllByIndex(String input, int dstIdx, int srcIdx) {
            return input.replace(input.charAt(dstIdx), input.charAt(srcIdx));
        }
```

Здесь функция `replaceAllByIndex` выполняет замену всех вхождений символа, находящегося по индексу `dstIdx` на символ с индексом `srcIdx` в строке `input`.

Однако если вашей целью стоит просто поменять местами два символа (а не все вхождения), то используйте следующую функцию вместо `replaceAllByIndex` в коде выше:

```
        public static String swapChars(String input, int lIdx, int rIdx) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
            sb.setCharAt(lIdx, input.charAt(rIdx));
            sb.setCharAt(rIdx, input.charAt(lIdx));
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

Выводы программы в первом и во втором случае соответственно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -2):

```
        String s = "d1234567389";
        String newString = s.replace(s.charAt(3) + "", s.charAt(0) + "");
        System.out.println(newString);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Такая замена может упасть на строке типа `"$$$^+++|-$-|"`

Comment: @AlexRudenko, правда Ваша. Не подумал про спецсимволы :) Поправил.